# Matrix representation of the Clifford group

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-information, group-theory, group-representations, software

The Clifford group $C_n$ on $n$ qubits is defined as
$$C_n = \left\{ U \in U(2^n) \mid \sigma \in P_n \rightarrow U\sigma U^\dagger \in P_n \right\}/U(1),$$
where
$$P_n = \left\{ \sigma_1 \otimes \dots \otimes \sigma_n \mid \sigma_i \in \{I,X,Y,Z\} \right\},$$
and $X,Y,Z$ are the Pauli matrices. Also $C_n$ may be generated as
$$<H_i,P_i,CNOT_{ij}>/U(1).$$

How exactly could one produce a matrix representation of $C_n$ for use in a program? I understand the abstract representation, however it seems quite difficult to obtain an explicit list of the elements.

Comment: not sure you realize the difficulty of the question you are asking, but this https://arxiv.org/pdf/1310.6813.pdf (and references therein) might give you a starting point.  Even for a single qubit the Clifford group contains something like 192 elements so anything beyond the generators is usually abstract.

Comment: Why here (http://home.lu.lv/~sd20008/papers/essays/Clifford%20group%20[paper].pdf) does it say the Clifford group $C_1$  contains 24 elements. If I consider $C_1$, how can I construct the list of elements via a matrix representation?

Comment: There is a factor of $8$ difference, probably due to some equivalence. 
 Either way...  in the case of ${\cal C}(1)$, start with the generators and systematically multiply them together.  Basically since $H^2=1$ and $S^4=1$, you will have all "words" of the type $H$, $S$, $SH$, $HS$ etc never containing $H^2$ or $S^4$.   It's a process by exhaustion and it can be quite long.

Comment: Any idea how long it would need to be for $C_1$? Seems to me this algorithm would be at least $O(n^2)$ where $n$ is potentially much larger than $\lvert C_n \rvert$? So constructing the clifford group beyond $C_1$ or $C_2$ would take very long.

Comment: You shouldn't use a matrix representation in a computer.  You loose all the advantage of the stabilizer formalism (being a concise description) immediately!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are algorithms to generate all elements of the Clifford group for a specified number of qubits. Here are a few implementations:

- Algorithms that can enumerate an arbitrary Clifford operator without having to generate all possible tableaux (which makes it exponentially more efficient if all you need is just a random sample of the Clifford group). See https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.2170.pdf. Implemented in [`QuantumClifford.jl`](https://quantumsavory.github.io/QuantumClifford.jl/stable/API/#QuantumClifford.enumerate_cliffords-Tuple%7BAny,%20Any%7D)
- **A very inefficient algorithm**: http://www.cgranade.com/python-quaec/ (see `qecc.clifford_group`). The code implementing this can be seen [here](https://github.com/cgranade/python-quaec/blob/9e77f68671cd347811b7105a3431d867e0a35490/src/qecc/CliffordClass.py#L373). It basically generates all possible mappings and then filters out those that do not fulfill the commutation and anticommutation relations. The section "Number of Elements" of [this](http://home.lu.lv/%7Esd20008/papers/essays/Clifford%20group%20%5Bpaper%5D.pdf) goes in a bit more depth.

In the [`QuantumClifford.jl`](https://github.com/QuantumSavory/QuantumClifford.jl) library you can also convert these Clifford operations represented as tableaux into unitary matrices.

````
julia> using QuantumOptics, QuantumClifford

julia> a = first(enumerate_cliffords(2))
X₁ ⟼ + X_
X₂ ⟼ + _Z
Z₁ ⟼ + Z_
Z₂ ⟼ + _X

julia> Operator(a)
Operator(dim=4x4)
  basis: [Spin(1/2) ⊗ Spin(1/2)]
 0.353553+0.0im       0.0+0.0im   0.353553+0.0im        0.0+0.0im
      0.0+0.0im  0.353553+0.0im        0.0+0.0im   0.353553+0.0im
 0.353553+0.0im       0.0+0.0im  -0.353553+0.0im        0.0+0.0im
      0.0+0.0im  0.353553+0.0im        0.0+0.0im  -0.353553+0.0im
```
````